how to downgrade from Ubuntu 24.04
Ubuntu 24.04 won't let me access localhost. How do I roll back to the last version?

What does "Ubuntu 24.04 won't let me access localhost." mean? Please [edit] your question and give more details to avoid an XY problem ( https://xyproblem.info/ )!

You roll back by using whatever backup strategy you put into place, and we can't know what that was unless you tell us. Debian/Ubuntu tools are intended to go forward; backwards is very manual (and on a package level) which is why you just restore data from your backups to go backwards.  You gave no specifics as to what you're trying to achieve; but you can non-destructively re-install too in some cases - but examine exactly what you're trying to do as you've not told us clearly.

Why does it matter why I want to roll back the installation of malfunctioning software? The "upgrade" was suggested and handled by Jammy Jellyfish. Allowing it has made it impossible for me to test code for a project under development because browsers are "Unable to connect". The ONLY difference between accessing the site the last 5231 times and now was the "upgrade". I don't care why the OS is flaky. I just want to return to a stable, fully tested environment.

Restore your system from your backups then... as already stated, the Debian package tools used by Ubuntu allow you to upgrade to newer packages in an automatic or semi-automatic method, but backwards is manual (ie. package by package) and under your control....   If you have a day or more, you can do that for whatever pacakges were updated (your system logs will tell you that; only you know what system & packages you have installed) but given that will take such a long time... restoring from backups is the easy solution...  Non-destructive re-install works only for desktop systems...
